# Adding Facebook Comments to Dreamweaver Template

Tags: facebook, dreamweaver, facebook-comments

I followed the directions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ to add a comment box to my Dreamweaver template and it worked - but all comments made show up on all pages, no matter which page the comment was actually made on. Plus, when it posts to a user's profile, it just links to "beachpaper.com." How do I tell the code that I don't just want a comment box for the domain URL - I want it to automatically know what page it's on and make a comment box that's independent from the others on the site? Is there anyway to do this without manually changing the code on each page?